# how do I install python library on AWS EMR notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-emr, jupyter-lab

I want to install additional libraries on AWS notebook (connected to EMR cluster), however I do not see any option to connect from Notebook to internet. If I do "pip install ", it always come back saying that network is not reachable. I am not sure which network need to be changed for network connection and library installation.

I did login to Jupyter terminal, and ping to google.com, which just timed out. I do not see any network / security group etc... configuration under Notebook section for making any relevant changes.

May be I need to take some additional steps?

Comment: Have you looked at [Install Python libraries on a running cluster with EMR Notebooks](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/install-python-libraries-on-a-running-cluster-with-emr-notebooks/)?

Answer (score 6):

#### Three methods are available for installing packages:

1. Installing notebook-scoped libraries allows packages to reside within the EMR notebook instance.
2. Installing libraries on the master node of the EMR cluster makes them accessible to the EMR notebook. However, these packages may not be available on worker nodes.
3. Utilizing EMR Bootstrap actions enables package installation on both master and worker nodes.

#### 1. Notebook-scoped libraries

For **PySpark kernel**, libraries can be installed using:

```py
sc.install_pypi_package("celery")
```

List installed libraries with:

```py
sc.list_packages()
```

Install a package specifying version and repository:

```py
sc.install_pypi_package("arrow==0.14.0", "https://pypi.org/simple")
```

#### 2. Installing kernels and Python libraries on a cluster master node

Option A:

```
%pip install pmdarima
```

Option B: Connect to the master node via SSH and execute:

```
sudo pip3 install -U matplotlib
sudo pip3 install -U pmdarima
```

Option C: Using spark magic

```
%%sh
/emr/notebook-env/bin/pip install -U matplotlib
/emr/notebook-env/bin/pip install -U pmdarima
```

For additional information, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-installing-libraries-and-kernels.html).

For Python 3 kernel, there is no direct method for installing extra libraries except by uploading the Python package to the notebook and using the JupyterLab terminal to run:

```
pip install package.tar.gz
```

Comment: You can also specify package version e.g. `sc.install_pypi_package("pandas==0.25.1")`

Comment: what about installing a package from s3?

Comment: How to install r packages ?

Comment: I am trying to install fasttext on EMR notebook, like this - "sc.install_pypi_package("fasttext"). and failed with gcc error. This is what worked - "%pip install fasttext"